# how to make Active/ Inactive submitted Value into database

Tags: php, database, mysqli

Hi any one can help me,

i want Active / Inactive data when user submit value , that information need to store in database show active/ inactive.

how it possible help me?

Comment: you can find countless examples and working codes, just google it...

Answer (score 0):

for storing active/ inactive in DB you can use tinyint for ex:0 for active and 1 for inactive and just comment in comment section for field in DB as you had used 0 for active and 1 for inactive ,so while storing you need to pass value 0 for active and 1 for inactive